# Isotope with longest decay chain to reach a stable isotope

Tags: nuclear-physics

Which decay chain of a radioactive isotope has the most 'steps' before reaching a stable isotope, i.e. decays into the most other isotopes before becoming stable?

Comment: for clarity, not about the time taken to decay.

Comment: Who gave here a minus? And why?

Answer (score 5):

In a sense, this question is unanswerable. (Still a good question!) 
}
Consider the ***natural*** decay chain of $_{92}U^{238}$.  This isotope goes through 14 steps, along various routes, to decay to $_{82}Pb^{206}$. This $4n+2$ series is the longest **naturally** occurring one. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain

However, someone could immediately claim that they have some $_{94}Pu^{242}$ which decays almost at once by $\alpha$-emission to $_{92}U^{238}$.  The someone jumps up with some $_{96}Cm^{246}$, and so on, and so on.

Comment: One could imagine that, at some point along the line of superheavy elements, fission becomes more probable than alpha emission, which would end this particular chain. But we don't know where that might happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just made a small Python that builds a graph from a "decay.txt" file I found somewhere. Longest path in it is:

Sg263->Rf259->Lr259->No259->Md259->Es255->Bk251->Cf251->Cm247->Pu243->Am243->Np239->Pu239->U235->Th231->Pa231->Ac227->Fr223->At219->Rn219->Po215->Pb211->Bi211->Tl207->Pb207

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research on this, and the longest decay chain is Og-293*→Lv-289→Fl-285→Cn-281→Ds-277→Hs-273→Sg-269→Rf-265→No-261→Fm-257→Cf-253→Es-253→Bk-249→Cf-249→Cm-245→Pu-241→Am-241→Np-237→Pa-233→U-233→Th-229→Ra-225→Ac-225→Fr-221→At-217→Bi-213→Po-213→Pb-209→Bi-209→Tl-205

*Og-293, although theoretically more stable than the only discovered isotope of Oganesson (Og-294), has not been discovered, but it will probably be in the not too distant future. I have also checked decay chains for other theoretical isotopes of Oganesson such as Og-300, but their decay chains are very short due to spontaneous fission. If you want the longest decay chain for isotopes that are known to exist, then just remove the Og-293 from the decay chain.